# Liesel arrives having just stolen her first book

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

From [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816442/) it says

> Liesel **arrives** having just stolen her first book

Does *arrives* mean *to achieve an aim* here? (I found this in meaning in this [online dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/arrive) as an informal way of saying it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in this case, no. With extra context:

> ...she is taken at age 9 to live with a foster family in a German working-class neighborhood. Liesel arrives having just stolen her first book...

In this case, "arrives" is meant literally: "to reach a place". Liesel arrives **at her new home**, just after stealing a book.